# Can i user pattern in @Html.Editor In MVC?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

we can use pattern(regex) for inputs control
like that :

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
```

My question is can i user Pattern in @html.Editor ?

I tried to use this way:

```
@Html.Editor("country_code", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , required = "required" , pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"} })
```

But *pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"* does not recognize

Comment: I have tried your code and It's working fine.Can you please add form tag code so I can see what really happens in your code ?

Comment: intellisense get PatternMatcher class I thought it can not be used

Comment: It can be used even I have used it many times but it is not possible to say what is going wrong with your code without having an required code to look

Comment: i I think the problem is Visual Studio intellisense